# scp with jump host two keys and user change on jump host

Tags: ssh, scp

I have a a ssh jump server and there I have to do `sudo target` to arrive at the target.
On local I have a id_rsa and on the jump I have to use roots id_rsa.

With the following config a can do on local `ssh target`:

```
Host jumphost
    User jumpUser
 
Host target
    RemoteCommand sudo ssh targetIP
    RequestTTY yes
    Hostname jumphost
    User jumpUser
```

And I want to copy files between local and target.
Unfortunately, `scp target:/etc/hostname ./` gives me the wrong file from jumphost.

What did not work:

- use -oProxyCommand or -oProxyJump
- `ssh target "cat /etc/hostname"` -> Cannot execute command-line and remote command.
- `ssh -L 12345:targetIp:22` + `scp -P 12345 xxx yyy` connects to target but scp request a password

So the question is: how to copy files?

Comment: It's probably not the only problem you have, but I do not think `RemoteCommand sudo ssh targetIP` can work together with `scp`. The `RemoteCommand` would have to incorporate the `scp` command somehow.

Comment: Well, if you "steal" the root's `id_rsa` from the jump beforehand (either by just copying the file, or by adding the key to your local agent (this requires a trick with agent forwarding)) and let your local `ssh` use it, then your try with `ssh -L` may work. Seems inelegant, but an SSH connection where you have to `sudo` mid-way is not exactly elegant either.